# Display image for first sticky post only

Tags: images, sticky-post

Working on news paper site here i am using sticky.I want display first 6 sticky post its displaying very good but problem is that every sticky showing there post image(feature image) here i just want display image for the first sticky only and for other 5 sticky i want display only tittle of the post.

```
<ul>
<?php 

$args = array(
            'category_name' => 'महाराष्ट्र',
            'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
            'showposts' => '6',

        );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
  <li>      <div class="thumbnail_class"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(342,173), array ('class' => 'alignleft1')); ?></a></div>
        <div class="link_contect"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div><li>
      <?php 
    endwhile;

?>
</ul>
```

Comment: `showposts` is depreciated long time ago. You should be using `posts_per_page`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<ul>
<?php 

$args = array(
            'category_name' => 'महाराष्ट्र',
            'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
            'showposts' => '6',

        );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  $count = 1;

    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

  <li>      
  <?php if ( 1 == $count ): ?>
<div class="thumbnail_class"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php     the_post_thumbnail(array(342,173), array ('class' => 'alignleft1')); ?></a></div>

  <?php endif ?>

    <div class="link_contect"><a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php     the_title(); ?></a></div><li>
      <?php 
    $count++;
    endwhile;

?>
</ul>
```

Here `count` variable used for detecting first post. It is initialized to `1`. In another iteration its value is increased. so `if` condition would be `false` and does not display post image.

Comment: working perfectly great answer really appreciate. +1 from me